# Spring Data JPA- Having two JPA entities that reference a database table that isnt an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Bit of a use case question.
We want to create a new application with new JPA entity's X and Y, we want to be able to create a reference/relationship inside one of our JPA entity's x to an already existing database table z in the same database.
We dont want this new application to be able to manage the data in table z( another application does that) but just essentially read from it.
Essentially table X in JPA would have a collection of Z objects in a one to many relationship mapped by Z's primary key

Anyone got any insights of what we need to do to implement this?

Comment: Provide the proper mapping in the `ManyToOne` and use the z table as join table.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't quite understand

Comment: Use the `@JoinTable` to join the entities. You probably need an `@ManyToMany` instead of many to one. All of this is explained in the JPA guide (or hibernate as well) how to map entities using a join table.

Comment: I would also recommend going through https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqi/index.html, which highlight `Unidirectional` and `Bidirectional` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to create a new database user with READ-WRITE permission on all the tables, except those where you need READ-ONLY permission. You will use this newly created user in datasource connection with the guarantee that your application will not execute unwanted modifications.

For formal correctness you should also mark readonly `@Immutable` read-only entities